# How to scrape a flash video application with php

Tags: php, flash

There is a page that I want to scrape and it has a flash application.. when I take the whole page and paste it on my localhost, it doesnt play.

I know that the markup of the flash application looks something like this:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" 
codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,115,0" width="1" height="1" id="flash8" align="middle">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="movie" value="http://www.ecam.com/swf/flash8.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
<embed src="http://www.ecam.com/swf/swf/flash8.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="1" height="1" name="flash8" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

But I dont know what else to scrape, so that I fetch the flash application. please help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would not play because of the path

```
  <param name="movie" value="/swf/flash8.swf" />
                                 ^----------- this is not on your local host
```

You need to replace with something like

```
  <param name="movie" value="http://istoleit.com/swf/flash8.swf" />
```

Or Download it and put the right path ....

Comment: hmm.. i added the value..still doesnt work... so the otehr solution is to download it? downloading it is not an option cause it is a livestream on another site

Comment: Hot links as bee disabled then ... ... you need to download separately then include it to your page  @Dmitry Makovetskiyd

Comment: what do you mean by hot links being disabled? why cant i scrape the mark up of the html and put it on my site

Comment: See what is Hot Linking : http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/what-is-hot-linking-how-do-i-enable-and-disable-hotlink-protection ......

Comment: are you sure there is a hotlink protection for a flash application?